# Scikit Decision Tree Error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I got the error when trying to visualize the predicted label for my testing data.

```
import scipy.io
from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np
import pydot
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO



  def main():
        mat  = scipy.io.loadmat('m.mat')
        x = np.array(mat['m'][:,:3])
        y = np.array(mat['m'][:,3])
        print ("training data: ",x)
        print ("training label: ", y)
        testdata = np.loadtxt('testing.txt')
        print ("testing data: ",testdata)
        exit
        clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20, random_state=99, criterion = "entropy")
        clf = clf.fit(x, y)
        clf = clf.predict(testdata)
        print ("NewLabel:",clf)
        import pydot
        out = StringIO()
        tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=out)
        pydot.graph_from_dot_data(out.getvalue()).write_pdf("output.pdf")
```

The output label looks in the correct format:

> ```
> ('training data: ', array([[  1.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
>        [  1.00000000e+00,   1.60000000e+02,   3.10000000e+01],
>        [  1.00000000e+00,   4.38000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00],
>        ..., 
>        [  1.84200000e+03,   2.60830000e+04,   7.80000000e-01],
>        [  1.84200000e+03,   2.61810000e+04,   5.20000000e-01],
>        [  1.84200000e+03,   2.61840000e+04,   1.00000000e+00]]))
> ('training label: ', array([ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.]))
> ('testing data: ', array([[  1.00000000e+00,   1.51000000e+02,   3.00000000e+00],
>        [  1.00000000e+00,   1.60000000e+02,   3.30000000e+01],
>        [  1.00000000e+00,   2.65000000e+02,   3.00000000e+00],
>        ..., 
>        [  9.52000000e+02,   2.59300000e+04,   2.60000000e+01],
>        [  9.52000000e+02,   2.60830000e+04,   9.60000000e-01],
>        [  9.52000000e+02,   2.61810000e+04,   1.00000000e+00]]))
> ('NewLabel:', array([ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.]))
> ```

And I got the error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DT.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "DT.py", line 24, in main
    tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=out)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/tree/export.py", line 131, in export_graphviz
    recurse(decision_tree.tree_, 0)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tree_'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to clf.predict()?  That returns an array which is overwriting your DecisionTreeClassifier

Comment: I'm not familiar with ``pydot``, but it looks like it expects to be passed a Decision Tree object, and you're passing it a NumPy array. You should remove the ``clf = clf.predict(testdata)`` line, as ``predict`` returns an array.

Comment: @jeffcarey Thanks, looks like that's the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @jakevdp Thanks! that's right!